# Image name has to be passed onclick of a link and image should appear in another div

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am a newbie in this web field.
I am stuck up with a problem as.....
I have list of links in one div and if I click on that particular link, image related to that link should appear in another div. Name for that image I am retrieving from database, so it should be passed to that div and that image should be seen in that div.

I saw many examples related to jquery and javascript but didn't find a particular example. As I am very new I am not good in editing and fixing those examples as per my requirement.
Need Help.

Am using cakephp framework for development

Here All my links are created

```
<?php foreach($news as $count): ?>
<div class="title">
        <a href="#"> <?php echo $count['News']['title'];?> </a> 

</div>
```

there is a div outside this foreach

```
<div id="vedio-image">
          <?php // $this->Html->image($count['New']['vedioImage']); ?>
</div>
```

How can i use $count['News']['vedioImage'] outside for loop and pass it to jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you have HTML something like this.

```
<?php foreach($news as $count): ?>
<div class="title"> <a href="#" rel="<?php echo $count['News']['image'];?>"> <?php echo $count['News']['title'];?> </a> </div>
<?php endforeach;?>


<!--Another div to show image -->
<div id="vedio-image"></div>
```

What you can do is add image path to anchor's (a) rel attribute like this.

Now here comes the jQuery

```
$('div.title a').click(function(){ 
    $('#vedio-image').html('<img src="' + $(this).attr('rel') + '" />'); 
});
```

if you writing javascript in header just include above code in ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div.title a').click(function(){ 
        $('#vedio-image').html('<img src="' + $(this).attr('rel') + '" />'); 
    });
});
```

Hope this helps, else provide little more information about your code.

Comment: hey there thanks for your replay. But I am showing those links inside foreach loop <?php foreach($news as $count): ?><div class="title">
                                        <a href="#"> <?php echo $count['News']['title'];?> </a> 
                                    
                                    </div><?php endforeach;?> and <div id=vedio-image> is outside this for loop and inside this div i have to show the image and that image name is retrived in for loop

Comment: check the answer now... Just modified as per your requirement